# Powershell find files with same name in multiple directories and replace the file with new file

Tags: powershell

I'd like to use powershell to find multiple files called q.jpg in D:\abc folder and all subfolders and then replace all q.jpg with a new q.jpg located in folder D:\updates.
I've tried different commands but keep getting red error fails.

Comment: *I've tried different commands, but won't show you any of them* is like the schoolboy telling the teacher *Honest, I did my homework! But my dog ate it*. If it's not in your post, it didn't happen. Questions that say *I tried but it didn't work. Plz give me teh codez* don't usually do too well here.

Comment: Here is what i have been trying to get to work based on my trials and errors:  $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\abc' -Recurse -File -Include "q.jpg" foreach($b in $bins)  {Copy-Item -Path D:\updates\q.jpg -Destination $b.FullName -Force}

Comment: Don't extend your question in comments, edit your question instead and format code properly.

Comment: Include all errors the code throws as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
#long version
Get-ChildItem "D:\ABC" -Recurse -file -filter "q.txt" | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item "D:\updates\q.txt" $_.FullName }

#quick version
gci "D:\ABC" -R -file -fi "q.txt" | %{cpi "D:\updates\q.txt" $_.FullName }
```

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation with code as this makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers.